# TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) with javascript & react hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I was trying to make a simple d3 `Data-Driven Documents` pie chart with React `hooks` along with Nextjs and a tailwindcss.

Just trying to render a list of items that is `Number of people registered the application` and `Number of people onBoarded` in the pie chart, it keeps throwing this error indicating it's `undefined`.

Here's my code, Please let me know know if I'm doing anything wrong.

```
/pages/dashboard/index.js

import {useState, useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import * as d3 from 'd3';

function Index() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {type: 'registered', value: 40},
        {type: 'onboarded', value: 32},
    ]);

    const svgRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {

        //setting up svg container
        const w = 320;
        const h = 330;
        const radius = w / 2;
        const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)
            .style('overflow', 'visible')

        //setting up chart
        const formattedData = d3.pie().value(d => d.value)(data);
        const arcGenerator = d3.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(radius);
        const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemaSet2);

        //setting up svgData
        svg.selectAll()
            .data(formattedData)
            .join('path')
            .attr('d', arcGenerator)
            .attr('fill', d => color(d.value))
            .attr('opacity', 0.7)

        //setting up annotation
        svg.selectAll()
            .data(formattedData)
            .join('text')
            .text(d => d.data.property)
            .attr('transform', d => `translate(${arcGenerator.centroid(d)})`)
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle');
    }, [data])
    
   return (
    <div className="md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">
      <div className="h-full py-4 px-4 space-y-6 rounded-xl border border-light bg-white">
       <svg className="w-40 m-auto opacity-75" ref={svgRef}></svg>
         <div>
          <h5 className="text-xl text-gray-600 text-center">Number of people registered</h5>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
);
```

[image: Here's an image to the error]

Comment: In what line is that error occurring, what's the stack trace?

Comment: `const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemaSet2);` in useEffect this is where it's throwing the error, alsoI don't see any div inside an svg  @Bergi

Comment: Oh right I was confused by the indentation, the `<div>` is after the `<svg>` not inside it